# Zsh ls tab completion on symlink does not follow the symlink

Tags: zsh, symlink, tab-completion

I have a folder in the home directory: `hdd -> /hdd`.

`ls -l hdd` outputs `hdd -> /hdd`. I expected it to follow the symlink and show the contents of `/hdd`, but that's not the main point.

`ls -l hdd/` outputs the contents of `/hdd`, as expected.

`ls -l hd` followed by a tab completion which then shows `ls -l hdd/`, then hitting `ENTER` will run the command `ls -l hdd`, **NOT** `ls -l hdd/`. Thus, it shows `hdd -> /hdd`, rather than the contents of `/hdd`.

Why is `ls -l hdd` the command being run when it tab completes `ls -l hdd/`? Which is generally the preferred behavior? If I manually typed `ls -l hdd/` without using any completion, it will of course show the contents of `/hdd`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the option `AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH`, which is by default enabled:

> **AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH** 
>   When the last character resulting from a completion is a slash and the next character typed is  a  word  delimiter,  a slash, or a character that ends a command (such as a semicolon or an ampersand), remove the slash.

You can disable it with

```
setop noautoremoveslash
```

---

You can also can configure `zle` to highlight slashes (and - depending on configuration - other suffices) which it would remove automatically. For example make it pink and bold:

```
zle_highlight[(r)suffix:*]="suffix:fg=magenta,bold"
```

**Note**: This might not work in conjunction with the external [*zsh-syntax-highlighting* plugin](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting).